# Cakephp Mail delaying user sign up

Tags: cakephp

I am using cakephp framework for my web application development. My application will send welcome email after user entering his information. After this only it will display 'Sign Success' message. Unfortunately CakeEmail taking around 6 seconds to send a mail, so my sign up approximately taking 8 seconds. So how can I speed up the sign up process without removing CakeEmail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should defer sending of the email so that the user doesn't have to wait for the email to be sent before rendering any content. Whether the email has been sent or not makes no difference to the user seeing your 'Sign Success' page so shouldn't be responsible for increasing page response time.

Take a look at using something like the [Queue plugin for CakePHP](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-queue) to defer sending of email. This would allow you to log that an email needs to be sent after the user's data has been saved. You'd then setup a task for sending the email. The task would executed the next time the queue is run (for example, by a cronjob).